# Archiving log file using log4j2 2.5

Tags: java, xml, configuration, archive, log4j2

I have been trying to archive my application logs file which are older than a certain period. Noticed that since log4j 2.5 we have a `Delete`tag which let's you define the criteria based on which we can delete/archive our logs. Tried using this but I am somehow not able to crack it. Tried with a 30day `30d` value and that isn't working on my server and neither is a 20 second policy `PT20S` working in my Dev Machine.

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

XML is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="C://logs///test.log" filePattern="C://logs//test-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz" ignoreExceptions="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="C://logs//" maxDepth="2">
          <IfFileName glob="*/test-*.log.gz" />
          <IfLastModified age="PT20S" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
   </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: You can debug by setting `<Configuration status="trace">` in the beginning of the configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows the file and filePattern of the RollingFile appender can use single slashes. The double slashes may confuse it.

You can debug by setting `<Configuration status="trace">` in the beginning of the configuration file.

---

Update:

The rolled over files end up in the c:/logs directory (`filePattern="C://logs//test-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz"`).

However, the Delete action is configured to only look at files ending in "log.gz" that are in  *subdirectories* of c:/logs. Files in the c:/logs directory itself are not matched by `glob="*/test-*.log.gz"`.

To fix this, use `glob="test-*.log.gz"`.
It was mentioned in the comments that changing glob to regex also resolved the problem.

Comment: Target machine is going to be a Unix server. Trying to figure out the issue in my Win Dev Machine. Let me try out the debug setting. Is there anything else in the config that looks glaringly obvious to you?

Comment: I may have found something. Updated my answer.

Comment: That was indeed the issue. changing glob to regex kicked in the log archival. Sorry the delay in response.
Also, Can you update your comment as an answer and also with the glob/regex change so that I can accept that?

Comment: Instead of changing glob to regex, I believe the path in the glob should be changed to `test-*.log.gz`. I've updated my answer. I think the regular expression would be more complex.